# Callback Function in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am setting up the callback function for the validation in CodeIgniter but there is an error occurs which showing "Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name." Hope someone can help me to solve the problem.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php class User_Registration extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('UserRegistration');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $data['results'] = $this->UserRegistration->get_record();

        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('User_Registration', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Ins_ID', 'Ins_ID', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_Ins_ID');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Ins_Name', 'Ins_Name', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Gender', 'Gender', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Address', 'Address', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Contact_No', 'Contact_No', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Education_Level', 'Education_Level', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Commence_Date', 'Commence_Date', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('User_Name', 'User_Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_User_Name');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('Password', 'Password', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
            $data['results'] = $this->UserRegistration->get_record();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('User_Registration', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $my_action = $this->input->post('submit');
            if ($my_action == 'submit') {
                $this->UserRegistration->insert_record();
            }

            $data['results'] = $this->UserRegistration->get_record();

            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('Registration_Done');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
    }


    function check_Ins_ID($Ins_ID)
    {
        //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
        $Ins_ID = $this->input->post('Ins_ID');
        $result = $this->UserRegistration->check_ins_id($Ins_ID);
        //query the database

        if ($result) {
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_Ins_ID', 'Invalid Instructor ID.Please contact to the administration.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    function check_User_Name($User_Name)
    {
        //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
        $User_Name = $this->input->post('User_Name');
        $result = $this->UserRegistration->check_user_name($User_Name);
        //query the
        database

        if ($result) {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('check_User_Name', 'The User_Name already exist.Please use other User_Name.Thank you.');
            return TRUE;
        } else {
            return FALSE;

        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is my model:

```
function check_ins_id($Ins_ID)
{
    $this -> db -> select('Ins_ID');
    $this -> db -> from('user');
    $this -> db -> where('Ins_ID',$Ins_ID);
    $this -> db -> limit(1);
    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if ($query -> num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function check_user_name($User_Name)
{
    $this -> db -> select('User_Name');
    $this -> db -> from('login');
    $this -> db -> where('User_Name',$User_Name);
    $this -> db -> limit(1);
    $query = $this -> db -> get();

    if ($query -> num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if it helps:

```
function check_Ins_ID($Ins_ID)
{
     //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
     //$Ins_ID = $this->input->post('Ins_ID');                     //you are already getting this in your parameters
     $result = $this->UserRegistration->check_ins_id($Ins_ID);//query the database

     if($result)
     {
         return TRUE;
     }
     else
     {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_Ins_ID', 'Invalid Instructor ID.Please contact to the administration.');
        return false;
     }
 }
```

When you are calling the validation function, you are getting the field value in your callback function's parameter, not from the `$_POST`.

Comment: ya,the callback function is no problem but it shows a message"Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name." This message make the data cannot insert and save it to the database.

Comment: if I remove the second call back function "callback_check_User_Name".The message does not come out and it works but I need to set the validation for the User_Name.

Comment: Comment out this line `$User_Name = $this->input->post('User_Name');` inside your `"callback_check_User_Name"` function, inside your function `echo` the value you're getting for `$User_Name` and the `result` you're getting from the `database`.

Comment: ya.removed.The echo $result for the $User_Name = $this->input->post('User_Name'); does come out any values.I have compare the code with the first callback function,it still come out with the error.

Comment: remove the line `$User_Name = $this->input->post('User_Name');` from inside the function bro. You are getting `$User_Name` in your function  already. Now test again.

Comment: Sorry,I mentioned wrong line just now,should be echo "$result = $this->UserRegistration->check_user_name($User_Name);" nothings come out.The first callback function can work but the second got error.

Comment: I found the error where the model unable to get the value for the $User_Name but I had passed it to the model from controller.do you know where I doing wrong in getting the $User_Name in model?

Comment: Check inside the callback function the value of `$User_Name` which youre getting from the parameter before sending to the model, Now, if its blank, then check the `form element` name, it should be `User_Name`

Comment: I think the different is between int and string.do you know what should i return for the string since Ins_ID is int which using if ($query -> num_rows() == 1) {return $query->result();}. SO, for the string,it should be ($query -> num_rows() == '') {return XXX ;}.